# Remove method in Seaside

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, seaside

How does one remove a method in Squeak! Smalltalk? I'm using a Seaside 2.8.4 image and I've accidentally added a method and made a typo in the name. I renamed it, but then it just made a new method. How do I remove the old one? Google didn't turn anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the browser *yellow-click* on a method name in the rightmost pane and select *Remove method...*

Squeak identifies mouse buttons by the colors red, yellow and blue because the Alto computer for which Smalltalk-80 was originally developed had a mouse with three colored buttons.

The yellow button is usually the middle button on an Unix mouse and the right button on a Windows mouse. That's because the mice on Windows PCs tend to have only two buttons while the ones on Unix X11 workstations traditionally had three.

Comment: I neglected to add that for whatever reason, my right click button isn't working in the squeak image. It works everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, middle click does what I needed.

Comment: Squeak is multi-platform, so it works on Linux, Windows and Mac. Not all of those systems have three-button mice. There have been images where the mouse-buttons have been switched around, and ctrl-click, alt-click or cmd-click typically provide the needed menus. In the preferences of an image there are also settings to switch mouse-buttons around.